# Change the color cell according to similar text to Excel Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

how to write color cell changes if you find text in the index data in the result cells, then the text * in the result cells will change according to the color of the index data.

[image]

Comment: You can use conditional Formatting. Won't be as simple as you think, But it will do the Task

Answer (score 0):

**See the Demo below to Get the Idea on How to Apply the Conditional Formatting.**

**Steps:**

- Select all the Data
- Click On Conditional Formatting
- Click on Manage Rules
- Click on Add New Rule
- Select `Format on Cell Value` , Change the Selection to `Contains Specific Text`
- Enter The Text in the TextBox
- Repeat the Same 6 Times for 6 Criteria

[image]

Comment: on visual basic ?

Comment: You will have to write a Code yourself First for that as this is not a free coding site. Give it a Try and if you face any errors, you can post a Question again.